# Attribute error with Rect class in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am just starting off with pygame and python so no judgement *(thanks:))* but I have been trying to use `colliderect()` to check for collision of two `rect` (snake, food; I think). I keep getting this error. **AttributeError: 'Food' object has no attribute 'colliderect'** What am I doing wrong?

```
# main function
def main():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    FPS = 17
    run = True
    snake = Snake(random.randint(0, 400), random.randint(0, 400), 10, 10)
    food = Food(random.randint(0, 400), random.randint(0, 400), 10, 10)
    snakeVelocity_X = 0
    snakeVelocity_Y = 0
    lost = False
```

```
# snake object
# Rect object: Rect(x, y, width, height)
class Snake():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height

    def draw(self, gameScreen):
        pygame.draw.rect(gameScreen, colors.BLACK, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))

    # def get_head_position(self):
    #   return self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height

# food object
class Food():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.collide = False

    def draw(self, gameScreen):
        pygame.draw.rect(gameScreen, colors.YELLOW, (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))
```

```
# check for collision
        if food.colliderect(snake):
            print("collision")
```

Above is the code I think is sufficient to get my point across.

Ps. I am new to stackoverflow too any do/don'ts.

Comment: `food` seems to be an instance of `Food`. Why would you expect `food` to have a method `colliderect`? According to your code snippet you didn't define such a method.

Comment: @Matthias it is already a method of the Rect object from the Pygame module. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`colliderect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect) is a method of [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html). However `Food` is not a `pygame.Rect` object.

Remove the attributes `x`, `y`, `width` and `height, but add a` rect` attribute:

```py
class Food():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
        self.collide = False

    def draw(self, gameScreen):
        pygame.draw.rect(gameScreen, colors.YELLOW, self.rect)
```

Now you can use the method `colliderect` with `food.rect`:

```py
if food.rect.colliderect(snake):
    print("collision")
```